# Packet processing order in nftables

Tags: nftables

I am moving from iptables to nftables. I have a basic questions about the packet processing order in nftables.

Since one can create multiple tables of same type, say inet, and also chains can be created inside each table with different or the same priority, what will be the processing order.

For example, if I create following, what will be the order.

```
table inet t1 {
    chain INPUT {
        type filter hook input priority 20; policy accept;
        ...
    }
}


table inet t2 {
    chain INPUT {
        type filter hook input priority 20; policy accept;
        ...
    }
}
```

while I understand that chains are hooked to different inputs, I yet to understand the logic behind having different tables.

Apology if is a stupid or basic question

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The ordering in the example will be *undefined*, but both chains will be traversed (unless for example the packet gets dropped in the first chain seen).

### Netfilter and the Network/Routing stack provide the ordering

Here's the *Packet flow in Netfilter and General Networking* schematic:

[image: Packet flow in Netfilter and General Networking]

While it was made with *iptables* in mind, the overall behaviour is the same when applied to *nftables* with minor differences (eg: no separation between *mangle* and *filter*, it's all *filter* in *nftables* with the exception of mangle/OUTPUT which should probably be translated into *type route hook output*, or most of the bridge mingling between *ebtables* and *iptables* seen in the lower part <sub><sup>**UPDATE:**</sup></sub> <s>doesn't exist with *nftables*</s> exists but should be avoided by using *nftables* directly in the *bridge family* directly, and using kernel >= 5.3 if *conntrack* features are needed there (and by not using the kernel module `br_netfilter` at all).

### Role of tables

A table in *nftables* is not equivalent to a table in *iptables*: it's something less rigid. In *nftables*, the *table* is a container to organise chains, [*set*](https://wiki.nftables.org/wiki-nftables/index.php/Sets) and other kinds of objets, and limit their scope. Contrary to *iptables* It's perfectly acceptable and sometimes required to mix different chain types (eg: nat, filter, route) in the same table: for example that's the only way they can access a common *set* since it's scoped to the table and not global (like would be *iptables*' companion *ipset*).

Then it's also perfectly acceptable to have multiple tables of the same family including again the same kind of chains, for specific handling or to handle specific traffic: there's no risk of altering rules in an other table when changing the contents of this table (though there's still the risk of having clashing effects as an overall result). It helps managing rules. For example the [*nftlb*](https://github.com/zevenet/nftlb#how-it-works) load-balancer creates tables (in various families) all named *nftlb*, intended to be managed only by itself and not clashing with other user-defined tables.

### Ordering between hooks and within hooks

In a given family (netdev, bridge, arp, ip, ip6), chains registered to different hooks (ingress, prerouting, input, forward, output, postrouting) are ordered from the hook order provided by Netfilter as seen in the schematic above. Priority's scope is limited to the same hook and doesn't matter here. For example `type filter hook prerouting priority 500` still happens before `type filter hook forward priority -500` in the case of a forwarded packet.

Where applicable, for each possible hook of a given family, each chain will be competing with other chains registered at the same place. The *tables* play no role here, except defining the family. As long as the priority is different, within a given hook type, a packet will traverse chains within this hook from the lowest priority to the highest. If exactly the same priority is used for two chains of the same family and hook type, order becomes undefined. When creating chains, will the current kernel version add the chain before or after a chain with the same priority in the corresponding list structure? Will the next kernel version still keep the same behaviour or will some optimization change this order? It's not documented. Both hooks will still be called, but the order they are called in is undefined.

How could this matter? Here's as quote from [man page](https://manpages.debian.org/bullseye/nftables/nft.8) below, just to clarify that a packet can be accepted (or not) multiple times in the same hook:

> `accept`
>
> Terminate ruleset evaluation and accept the packet. The packet can
> still be dropped later by another hook, for instance accept in the
> forward hook still allows to drop the packet later in the postrouting
> hook, or another forward base chain that has a higher priority number
> and is evaluated afterwards in the processing pipeline.

For example if one chain accepts a certain packet, and the other chain drops this same packet, the overall result will always be a *drop*. But one hook might have done additional actions leading to side effects: for example it could have added the packet's source address in a *set* and the other chain called next have dropped the packet. If the order is reversed and the packet is dropped first, this "side effect" action will not have happened and the *set* will not have been updated. So one should avoid using the exact same priority in this case. For other cases, mostly when no drop happens, this would not matter. One should avoid using the same priority unless knowing it won't matter.

### Relation to other networking subsystems

Within a hook, all the *integer* range is available to choose the order, but some specific thresholds do matter.

From [*nftables*' wiki](https://wiki.nftables.org/wiki-nftables/index.php/Configuring_chains#Base_chain_priority), Here are the legacy *iptables* hook values valid for the *ip* family, which also include other subsystems:

> `NF_IP_PRI_CONNTRACK_DEFRAG (-400)`: priority of defragmentation
> `NF_IP_PRI_RAW (-300)`: traditional priority of the raw table placed before connection tracking operation
> `NF_IP_PRI_SELINUX_FIRST (-225)`: SELinux operations
> `NF_IP_PRI_CONNTRACK (-200)`: Connection tracking operations
> `NF_IP_PRI_MANGLE (-150)`: mangle operation
> `NF_IP_PRI_NAT_DST (-100)`: destination NAT
> `NF_IP_PRI_FILTER (0)`: filtering operation, the filter table
> `NF_IP_PRI_SECURITY (50)`: Place of security table where secmark can be set for example
> `NF_IP_PRI_NAT_SRC (100)`: source NAT
> `NF_IP_PRI_SELINUX_LAST (225)`: SELinux at packet exit
> `NF_IP_PRI_CONNTRACK_HELPER (300)`: connection tracking at exit

Of those only a few really matter: those not coming from *iptables*. For example (non-exhaustive) in the `ip` family:

- `NF_IP_PRI_CONNTRACK_DEFRAG (-400)`: for a chain to ever see incoming IPv4 fragments, it should register in *prerouting* at a priority lower than -400. After this only reassembled packets are seen (and rules checking for the presence of fragments never match).
- `NF_IP_PRI_CONNTRACK (-200)`: for a chain to act *before* *conntrack* it should register in *prerouting* or in *output* at a prority lower than -200. Example, register at priority `NF_IP_PRI_RAW (-300)` (or any other value < -200 but still > -400 if one want to match the port in all cases) to add a [`notrack`](https://wiki.nftables.org/wiki-nftables/index.php/Setting_packet_connection_tracking_metainformation#notrack) statement to prevent *conntrack* to create a connection entry for this packet. So the *nftables* equivalent of *iptables*' raw/PREROUTING is just *filter prerouting* with an adequate priority.

### Misc

Some special cases:

- the *inet* family registers within *ip* and *ip6* families' hooks at the same time.
- *type nat*

  It behaves differently when a rule matches and executes a NAT-related statement: the packet will not traverse further *nat* chains in the same hook. *type nat* registers differently. It has a fixed priority presence among other non-NAT hooks. For example in *prerouting* or *output* NAT hooks all happen at fixed priority  `NF_IP_PRI_NAT_DST` = -100 with regard to filter hooks. Multiple NAT hooks still respect the priority order between themselves. Additional details about *type nat* can be seen in this Q/A: [nftables: Are chains of multiple types all evaluated for a given hook?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/762402/nftables-are-chains-of-multiple-types-all-evaluated-for-a-given-hook)

  NAT rules from both *iptables-legacy* and *nftables* shouldn't be mixed with a kernel before 4.18. Before 4.18, the first facility among *iptables-legacy* and *nftables* to register would handle all of NAT in the hook.

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation. So is it correct say following?

"chains are grouped together by kernel from all the tables and ordered by priority irrespective of which table they come from. Table only serve as scope limiter for various elements chain is using for example sets, maps, etc"

Comment: Yes. Just don't forget the table's family. There's one "prerouting" per family and that's as many separately handled prerouting lists (ok,there are exceptions special cases related to netdev and inet families, and with nat).

Comment: @A.B For me it is still not clear what will be behaviour for multiple hooks registered in same family for same type of hook. E.g. inet filter hook priority 0 would accept ipv4 packet foo and ip filter hook priority 0 would drop packet foo. If inet hook happens to be evaluated first the "ruleset evaluation termination" is only for inet hook (and ip hook will drop the packet later)? or "ruleset evaluation termination" is for all filter hooks, or for all same priority filter hooks?

Comment: Rereading linked man page (especially wording around "queue" verdict statement) suggests that accept terminates evaluation of only current hook, (not whole ruleset like what is printed by nft list ruleset), and that same priority hook will be evaluated later.

Comment: @Slimak I'm sure I wrote it somewhere (maybe not this answer?) this is simple logic. If a packet is affected by two filters, then whatever the order of the filters the AND boolean operator's effect applies: DROP AND DROP => DROP,DROP AND ACCEPT => DROP, ACCEPT AND DROP => DROP, ACCEPT AND ACCEPT => ACCEPT. So the order of two chains (which is *undefined* if hooking at same priority without any more knowledge on the order it happened, the kernel version or the phase of the moon) doesn't matter: inet filter accept AND ip filter drop => DROP here <=>  ip filter drop AND inet filter accept => DROP

Comment: Thank you for this excellent summary of the different concepts and object roles in nftables. I'm sending this answer to a coworker who is transitioning from iptables because I couldn't explain it better.

Comment: @A.B it seems to be true, that when applying a dnat rule, no further dnat rules apply. However if you use `ip daddr set` instead of `dnat to`, further processing *will* happen. I (ab)used this fact to first DNAT my public IP into my k8s metallb load balancer network with nftables and then let kube-router apply its iptables DNAT rules to the final cluster IP.

Comment: @pschichtel That's correct, but I'm not sure it's relevant to this Q/A. Anyway `ip daddr set` is not used with the nat type which I mentioned. It's used for stateless NAT in a filter (or route) type hook and has to be used for every packet rather than only the first packet of the flow (with the alteration of other packets in the same flow offloaded to conntrack/nat). It could be useful for some cases, probably not all, to also set these packets as notrack or to mark them to avoid interactions with conntrack+nat.

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR

for the sake of understanding netfilter order of processing i prefer a more visual form : So I often refer to [Plouf](http://www.plouf.fr.eu.org/bazar/netfilter/schema_netfilter.txt)

```
                     (input interface)
                             |
                             v
                     /-------+-------\
                     | sanity checks |
                     \-------+-------/
                             |
                             v hook NF_IP_PRE_ROUTING
                      +------+------+
                      | conntrack   |
                      | defrag.     |
                      +-------------+
                      | mangle      |
                      | PREROUTING  |
                      +-------------+
                      | nat (dst)   |
                      | PREROUTING  |
                      +------+------+
                             |
                             v
        local delivery  /----+----\    forward
       +---------------+   route   +---------------+
       |                \---------/                |
       v                                           v
 /-----+-----\                               /-----+-----\
 |  defrag.  |                               | TTL check |
 \-----+-----/                               | dec. TTL  |
       |                                     \-----+-----/
       v hook NF_IP_LOCAL_IN                       |
+------+------+                                    |
| mangle  (1) |                                    |
| INPUT       |                                    |
+-------------+                                    |
| filter      |                                    v
| INPUT       |                              /-----+-----\
+-------------+                              | DF check  |
| nat (src)(2)|                              \-----+-----/
+-------------+                                    |
| conntrack   |                                    |
| confirm     |                                    | 
+------+------+                               hook v NF_IP_FORWARD
       |                                    +------+------+
       v                                    | mangle  (1) |
/-------+-------\                           | FORWARD     |
| local process |                           +-------------|
\-------+-------/                           | filter      |
       |                                    | FORWARD     |
       v                                    +------+------+
 /-----+-----\                                     |
 |   route   |                                     |
 |   frag.   |                                     |
 \-----+-----/                                     |
       |                                           |
       v hook NF_IP_LOCAL_OUT                      |
+------+------+                                    |
| conntrack   |                                    |
| defrag.     |                                    |
+-------------+                                    |
| mangle      |                                    |
| OUTPUT      |                                    |
+-------------+                                    v
| nat (dst)(3)|                              /-----+-----\
| OUTPUT      |                              |   frag.   |
+-------------+                              \-----+-----/
| filter      |                                    |
| OUTPUT      |                                    |
+------+------+                                    |
       |                                           |
       v                                           |
 /-----+-----\                                     |
 |  reroute  |                                     |
 \-----+-----/                                     |
       |                                           |
       +------------------+     +------------------+
                          |     |
                          v     v hook NF_IP_POST_ROUTING
                      +---+-----+---+
                      | mangle  (1) |
                      | POSTROUTING |
                      +-------------+
                      | nat (src)   |
                      | defrag.     |
                      | POSTROUTING |
                      +-------------+
                      | conntrack   |
                      | confirm     |
                      | frag.       |
                      +------+------+
                             |
                             v
                   (output interface)
```

Comment: `$ curl -v http://www.plouf.fr.eu.org/bazar/netfilter/schema_netfilter.txt 2>&1 >/dev/null |grep Last-Modified:` => `< Last-Modified: Fri, 13 Jan 2006 12:41:42 GMT` . 2006

Comment: you're right, it is incomplete however it stay true and in a simple form.