# nftables: Are chains of multiple types all evaluated for a given hook?

Tags: linux-kernel, nftables, netfilter

This is a question specifically about [nftables chain types](https://wiki.nftables.org/wiki-nftables/index.php/Configuring_chains#Base_chain_types) in the Linux kernel.

I don't understand how they're processed.  I've been staring at the kernel code for a while, and it looks to me like an nftables "chain" is attached to a netns as a hook entry (in e.g. `struct netns_nf.hooks_ipv4` for IPv4).

I don't see anything that discriminates on the "type" of the chain—`filter`, `nat`, or `route`—while creating or processing the chain.  It looks like all chain types would simply get stuffed in as hook entries, and only the `struct nf_hook_entry.hook` function would be type-specific.  For example, I think `nf_hook_entry.hook` would be the function `nft_nat_do_chain` for a `type nat` chain.

Looking at [this table of which combinations of family, hook, and type exist](https://wiki.nftables.org/wiki-nftables/index.php/Netfilter_hooks#Hooks_by_family_and_chain_type), let's say I added two chains to the `input` hook, one with `type filter` and one with `type nat`.  Let's further say that both chains are created with the same priority.

**Questions:**

1. Is my hypothetical scenario even possible, two chains on the same hook, only varying by type?  If not, where does the kernel prevent this?
2. If it is possible, what will determine the order that these two chains run in?  Is there something I'm missing that runs e.g. chains of `type nat` before chains of `type filter`?  Or will it be down to whichever chain was added first vs. second (and maybe kernel version, etc.)?

There is [an excellent related answer that's about chains with the same priority](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/607391/233999), but the specific case there is with two chains *of the same type*.

I am asking this question with the ultimate intent of understanding why nftables has a concept of "type" at all.

I know, for example, that the handler for `type route` chains may call `ip_route_me_harder` ([not a joke!](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/090472ed9c922e699dc61dd601a9b376a64f4390/net/ipv4/netfilter.c#L20)) if certain fields of a packet are changed by a chain, and this is unique to chains of `type route`.  I know `type nat` has a few restrictions on its priority.  I have also read that `type nat` chains are *only* called for the first packet of a connection, but I haven't been able to locate that exact restriction anywhere in the code (though maybe it's `nf_nat_inet_fn` in `nf_nat_core.c`?).

I appreciate any pointers you can give me to help me understand how and where `type` is handled for nftables chains in the kernel!

*Edit:* [This answer seems to suggest that nftables "types" are nearly a stylistic choice](https://serverfault.com/a/1110100/355648), though it does point out the special behaviors of the `route` type.  Another answer there further muddies *my* waters by saying that a NAT rule cannot be added to a chain of `type filter`, which (if true) is very confusing to me.  Where is such a restriction implemented?  (Only in userspace?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### TL;DR

When doing an experiment where a network namespace receives traffic and does NAT on it, one can see that whatever the priority given to the `type nat hook prerouting` chain, it doesn't matter with regard to the filter chains priorities: NAT always happen at exactly prerouting hook priority -100 aka `NF_IP_PRI_NAT_DST`. Priority between NAT chains themselves is preserved.

You looked at the `.hook` entries in definitions which are for actual actions during packet traversal, but overlooked the `.ops_register`/`.ops_unregister` entries defined only for NAT hooks which introduce a different behavior when the chain is registered.

Tests done with kernel 6.5.x and *nftables* 1.0.9, some links provided on https://elixir.bootlin.com/ with latest LTS kernel at this date without patch revision: 6.1 (not 6.1.x).

To summarize:

- NAT acts at special hook priorities, and only these priorities (rather than the priority given when adding the chain) are relevant when comparing with other hook types such as *filter* or *route*: NAT chains register differently than other chains. Still the given priorities apply internally between different NAT chains hooking at the same place.
- *route* follows normal priorities just like *filter* (no special registration).
- don't use exact priorities such as `NF_IP_PRI_NAT_DST` (or various other NAT-related exact values) elsewhere because then the precise interaction between how *nftables* and NAT hook into Netfilter might be undefined (example: could change depending on order of creation, or behavior could change depending on kernel version) instead of deterministic. For example use -101 or less to be before DNAT or -99 or more to be after DNAT but don't ever use -100 to avoid undefined behavior.
- the same warning applies for other special facilities' priorities, described for example [there](https://wiki.nftables.org/wiki-nftables/index.php/Netfilter_hooks#Priority_within_hook), such as `NF_IP_PRI_CONNTRACK_DEFRAG` or `NF_IP_PRI_CONNTRACK` etc. (and for *iptables* priorities when also interacting with *iptables* rules and needing a deterministic outcome).

---

### Experiment

I left aside cases such as family `inet`: one can just check it will behave the same with an adequate ruleset and test case.

Example ruleset (to be loaded using `nft -f ...`):

```
table t         # for idempotence
delete table t  # for idempotence

table t {
    chain pf1 {
        type filter hook prerouting priority -250; policy accept;

    udp dport 5555 meta nftrace set 1 counter
    }

    chain pf2 {
        type filter hook prerouting priority -101; policy accept;

    udp dport 5555 counter accept
    udp dport 6666 counter accept
    }

    chain pf3 {
        type filter hook prerouting priority -99; policy accept;

    udp dport 5555 counter accept
    udp dport 6666 counter accept
    }

    chain pn1 {
        type nat hook prerouting priority -160; policy accept;

        counter
    }

    chain pn2 {
        type nat hook prerouting priority 180; policy accept;

        udp dport 5555 counter dnat to :6666
    }

    chain pn3 {
        type nat hook prerouting priority -190; policy accept;

        counter
    }

    chain pn4 {
        type nat hook prerouting priority 190; policy accept;

        udp dport 5555 counter dnat to :7777
        udp dport 6666 counter dnat to :7777
    }

}
```

This ruleset will change a received UDP port 5555 into port 6666 instead in `pn2`. `pn1`, `pn3` and `pn4` are here just for priority between NAT chains (`pn4` also here to explain that NAT of a given type (DNAT, SNAT...) happens only once). There's a receiving application on UDP port 6666 (so the flow isn't deleted by an ICMP destination port unreachable), I used `socat UDP4-LISTEN:6666,fork EXEC:date` for this test and (interactively) sent two packets from a *remote* client using `socat UDP4:192.0.2.2:5555 -`.

One would believe that the NAT chain `pn2` with priority 180 performing a DNAT would happen *after* filter chain `pf3` with priority -99. But that's not what happens between `type nat` and other types: NAT is special. Using `nft monitor trace` like below:

```shell
# nft monitor trace
trace id 4ab9ba62 ip t pf1 packet: iif "lan0" ether saddr 8e:3e:82:1a:dc:87 ether daddr fa:2f:7e:2d:f1:03 ip saddr 192.0.2.1 ip daddr 192.0.2.2 ip dscp cs0 ip ecn not-ect ip ttl 64 ip id 49393 ip length 30 udp sport 58201 udp dport 5555 udp length 10 @th,64,16 0x610a
trace id 4ab9ba62 ip t pf1 rule udp dport 5555 meta nftrace set 1 counter packets 0 bytes 0 (verdict continue)
trace id 4ab9ba62 ip t pf1 verdict continue
trace id 4ab9ba62 ip t pf1 policy accept
trace id 4ab9ba62 ip t pf2 packet: iif "lan0" ether saddr 8e:3e:82:1a:dc:87 ether daddr fa:2f:7e:2d:f1:03 ip saddr 192.0.2.1 ip daddr 192.0.2.2 ip dscp cs0 ip ecn not-ect ip ttl 64 ip id 49393 ip length 30 udp sport 58201 udp dport 5555 udp length 10 @th,64,16 0x610a
trace id 4ab9ba62 ip t pf2 rule udp dport 5555 counter packets 0 bytes 0 accept (verdict accept)
trace id 4ab9ba62 ip t pn3 packet: iif "lan0" ether saddr 8e:3e:82:1a:dc:87 ether daddr fa:2f:7e:2d:f1:03 ip saddr 192.0.2.1 ip daddr 192.0.2.2 ip dscp cs0 ip ecn not-ect ip ttl 64 ip id 49393 ip length 30 udp sport 58201 udp dport 5555 udp length 10 @th,64,16 0x610a
trace id 4ab9ba62 ip t pn3 rule counter packets 0 bytes 0 (verdict continue)
trace id 4ab9ba62 ip t pn3 verdict continue
trace id 4ab9ba62 ip t pn3 policy accept
trace id 4ab9ba62 ip t pn1 packet: iif "lan0" ether saddr 8e:3e:82:1a:dc:87 ether daddr fa:2f:7e:2d:f1:03 ip saddr 192.0.2.1 ip daddr 192.0.2.2 ip dscp cs0 ip ecn not-ect ip ttl 64 ip id 49393 ip length 30 udp sport 58201 udp dport 5555 udp length 10 @th,64,16 0x610a
trace id 4ab9ba62 ip t pn1 rule counter packets 0 bytes 0 (verdict continue)
trace id 4ab9ba62 ip t pn1 verdict continue
trace id 4ab9ba62 ip t pn1 policy accept
trace id 4ab9ba62 ip t pn2 packet: iif "lan0" ether saddr 8e:3e:82:1a:dc:87 ether daddr fa:2f:7e:2d:f1:03 ip saddr 192.0.2.1 ip daddr 192.0.2.2 ip dscp cs0 ip ecn not-ect ip ttl 64 ip id 49393 ip length 30 udp sport 58201 udp dport 5555 udp length 10 @th,64,16 0x610a
trace id 4ab9ba62 ip t pn2 rule udp dport 5555 counter packets 0 bytes 0 dnat to :6666 (verdict accept)
trace id 4ab9ba62 ip t pf3 packet: iif "lan0" ether saddr 8e:3e:82:1a:dc:87 ether daddr fa:2f:7e:2d:f1:03 ip saddr 192.0.2.1 ip daddr 192.0.2.2 ip dscp cs0 ip ecn not-ect ip ttl 64 ip id 49393 ip length 30 udp sport 58201 udp dport 6666 udp length 10 @th,64,16 0x610a
trace id 4ab9ba62 ip t pf3 rule udp dport 6666 counter packets 0 bytes 0 accept (verdict accept)

trace id 46ad0497 ip t pf1 packet: iif "lan0" ether saddr 8e:3e:82:1a:dc:87 ether daddr fa:2f:7e:2d:f1:03 ip saddr 192.0.2.1 ip daddr 192.0.2.2 ip dscp cs0 ip ecn not-ect ip ttl 64 ip id 49394 ip length 30 udp sport 58201 udp dport 5555 udp length 10 @th,64,16 0x620a
trace id 46ad0497 ip t pf1 rule udp dport 5555 meta nftrace set 1 counter packets 0 bytes 0 (verdict continue)
trace id 46ad0497 ip t pf1 verdict continue
trace id 46ad0497 ip t pf1 policy accept
trace id 46ad0497 ip t pf2 packet: iif "lan0" ether saddr 8e:3e:82:1a:dc:87 ether daddr fa:2f:7e:2d:f1:03 ip saddr 192.0.2.1 ip daddr 192.0.2.2 ip dscp cs0 ip ecn not-ect ip ttl 64 ip id 49394 ip length 30 udp sport 58201 udp dport 5555 udp length 10 @th,64,16 0x620a
trace id 46ad0497 ip t pf2 rule udp dport 5555 counter packets 0 bytes 0 accept (verdict accept)
trace id 46ad0497 ip t pf3 packet: iif "lan0" ether saddr 8e:3e:82:1a:dc:87 ether daddr fa:2f:7e:2d:f1:03 ip saddr 192.0.2.1 ip daddr 192.0.2.2 ip dscp cs0 ip ecn not-ect ip ttl 64 ip id 49394 ip length 30 udp sport 58201 udp dport 6666 udp length 10 @th,64,16 0x620a
trace id 46ad0497 ip t pf3 rule udp dport 6666 counter packets 0 bytes 0 accept (verdict accept)
^C
```

one can see that all prerouting NAT hooks are happening between `pf2` and `pf3` ie between priorities -101 and -99: at priority -100 which is [`NF_IP_PRI_NAT_DST`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v6.1/source/include/uapi/linux/netfilter_ipv4.h#L38) as used in Netfilter's own structures [`static const struct nf_hook_ops nf_nat_ipv4_ops[]`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v6.1/source/net/netfilter/nf_nat_proto.c#L791). Chain `ip t pf3` sees port 6666 and not 5555.

If a NAT statement has been applied, following rules (in the same hook) are skipped by Netfilter so `pn4` never gets a chance here to be traversed at all in the example above (with only 2 packets of the same flow initially to port 5555) and never appears: this behavior also differs from `type filter` where the next hook is still traversed (eg: `pf3` is still traversed after `pf2`).

As usual, the next packet in the flow doesn't trigger any NAT chain anymore since only packet creating a new flow (conntrack state NEW) are sent to NAT chains, so the next packet doesn't even display traversing `pnX` chains anymore. Priorities between the four prerouting NAT chains are honored: priority order is `pn3` (-190) , `pn1` (-160), `pn2` (180) (and then there would be `pn4` (190) but it doesn't get the chance).

Note: the fact that the packets/bytes counters don't appear increased in the same run of `nft monitor trace` looks like a bug or a missing feature to me (they are incremented when checking `nft list ruleset`).

`type nat` hooks use [a different registering function than default for other *nftables* hooks](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v6.1/source/net/netfilter/nft_chain_nat.c#L51) so they can be handled differently:

> ```c
> .ops_register = nf_nat_ipv4_register_fn,
> .ops_unregister = nf_nat_ipv4_unregister_fn,
> ```

It's to be handled by NAT (which is managed by Netfilter) and in hook [`NF_INET_PRE_ROUTING`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v6.1/source/net/netfilter/nf_nat_proto.c#L792) (still provided by Netfilter to *nftables*) this will be done at priority `NF_IP_PRI_NAT_DST`.

This is not done for [type filter](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v6.1/source/net/netfilter/nft_chain_filter.c#L26) (nor [route](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v6.1/source/net/netfilter/nft_chain_route.c#L53)) which will then use a common *nftables* method rather than [the specified one](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v6.1/source/net/netfilter/nf_tables_api.c#L253).

Comment: I was hoping you'd answer this question :)  Thank you for this comprehensive answer.  You're right that I missed `ops_register`.  Reading through that code for a while, I think what I see is that registering a `type nat` chain actually causes nftables to put a standard set of "ops" (e.g. `nf_nat_ipv4_ops`) into Netfilter with one of the `NF_IP_PRI_NAT_*` priorities, and the actual rules appear to be stuffed into [the private pointer of the ops](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v6.1/source/net/netfilter/nf_nat_core.c#L1058).  That leads nicely into `nf_nat_inet_fn`...

Comment: ...where you can see the "NAT rules are only run once for the start of a connection" bits.

Thank you again for this comprehensive answer!  Your worked example was especially illuminating.